# Why is my tableview cell behaving differently when I swipe-delete at different speeds?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've uploaded a video of the behavior [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7ul5lfj8zr1d62/iOS%20Tableview%20Behavior.mov?dl=0) (dropbox link).

When I swipe-to-delete a cell quickly, the `UILabel` on the right side of the cell appears to move closer to the right edge of the cell. It stays there until I swipe-to-delete slowly. If I do slowly, the label always stays in the right spot and never seems to move.

The label is placed there with an AutoLayout constraint (trailing space to superview, the content view of the cell).

This began to occur after downloading the non-beta release of Xcode 6.3 and updating my device to iOS 8.3.

I've tried debugging the constraint pre/during/post editing, and the label's constraints are always correct. What could be happening?

Comment: what other constraints are on the label?

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/GyDQfgK.png) is a screenshot of all constraints on the label. In this screenshot, "nameLabel" is a `UILabel` on the other side of the cell constrained the same way, to the edges and to this label.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty weird. Just for fun, what happens if you remove the leading constraint to nameLabel